# Use of knockoutjs disable binding

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, jsfiddle

I am trying to get an input box to be disabled when a checkbox is checked. I'm trying to use Knockoutjs to get this done, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my html:

```
<input id="input1" type="text" placeholder="Something Here" 
data-bind="disable: makeInvalid"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk1" data-bind="checked: makeInvalid"/>
<label>Make Textarea Invalid</label>
```

Here is my js:

```
var viewModel = {
        makeInvalid : ko.observable(false),        
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("chk1"));
```

My fiddle is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/devEngine/3ag0881z/2/

I have attempted to follow knockout's instructions on the disable binding which they say is exactly the same as the enable binding, just in reverse:

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/enable-binding.html

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Also, add jquery & knockout files to your fiddle, it's normal your fiddle doesn't work without them :-)

Comment: @Shadowfox While Knockout can be used in combination with jQuery, Knockout does not have a dependency on jQuery (nor any other JavaScript library).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one is a super easy fix. Your apply bindings is only hitting the element with id chk1. The value of the observable will only be bound in that scope. Simply remove the second argument of your `ko.applyBindings` and it will work just fine.

```js
var viewModel = {
        makeInvalid : ko.observable(false),        
};
    
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input id="input1" type="text" placeholder="Something Here" 
data-bind="disable: makeInvalid"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk1" data-bind="checked: makeInvalid"/>
<label>Make Textarea Invalid</label>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for that response - much appreciated!  I see how that works; however what if I needed to explicitly specify an element so as to avoid the multiple bindings error later.  I will have numerous elements such as these in my form, you see.

Comment: Sorry, I think I got it - just wrap in a dedicated div.  Thanks again!

Comment: You can wrap it in a div, or use the `with` binding to specifiy an object as the view model. ( I prefer `with` so you can interact with the other views if needed.)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing knockout from your jsFiddle.

This is incorrect 
`ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("chk1"));` . You need to apply bindings to the input aswell as the checkbox. `ko.applyBindings(viewModel);`

See working jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/3ag0881z/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { disabled: isDisabled}, checked: isActive" />
```

.

```
var viewModel = {
        isDisabled: ko.observable(false),
        isActive : ko.observable(false)
};
```

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

**this is for enable/disable checkbox and also for checked/unchecked**